# Removing pad to polygon space in Eagle

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad

[image: Empty space around pad]

In Eagle, is there any way I can remove the empty space around the pad here?  I would like the polygon to connect to the whole pad.

Note that this is a pad from a part and not a via.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern you're seeing is called a thermal in Eagle. They're useful if the copper pour is very large and acts like a heat sink when soldering. The four thin traces connected to the pad limit the amount of heat being absorbed by the copper pour. The thermals are not always necessary though.

Eagle enables thermals by default. You can disable them two different ways.

1. When you select the polygon button [image] several options appear across the top of the window. Click the "Thermals Off" button [image] to disable thermals. All future polygons pours will remember that setting.
2. If you have already created the polygon pour, select the polygon using the info button. Uncheck the "Thermals" checkbox and click OK.
   [image]

Comment: I'd agree that the detail of the automated thermal in this case is not terrific, but exercise real consideration before removing them. Boards without can be extremely painful to solder.  If that mistake gets made, various tricks can help, like a preheater below the PCB, a co-worker with a second iron, or a hot-air desoldering rig aimed at the area while you try to solder it with an iron.  Also in contrast to `pads` means to be soldered, `vias` that exist only to connect layers usually don't have thermals.

Comment: If it is not desired to remove all thermals, you can insert a second polygon on the same net over the area of just the parts you don't want thermals for - that way you leave thermals 'on' for the full board polygon and turn the 'off' for the smaller local polygon.

Comment: But the real question is: **How do you remove only a few specific thermal isolation pads?** This is important for heat dissipation in power ICs. Is Tom Carpenter's answer the only way? Seems something important to be left out of a software like Eagle.